# Why does meteor doesn't work with either colors nor chalk npm modules

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use [chalk](https://www.npmjs.org/package/chalk) or [colors](https://www.npmjs.org/package/colors) within a meteor app to get prettier logs, but I **can't get them to work**. It simply prints the logs as if I were not using them.

I've tried using it in a nodejs app (without meteor) and they work fine.

Is there something special meteor does with `console.log`?

Sample code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var chalk = Meteor.require('chalk')
    console.log( chalk.blue('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' ))
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chalk works smooth with meteor, you just need to  enable it:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        var chalk = Meteor.npmRequire('chalk');

        chalk.enabled = true;

        console.log( chalk.red('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' ))
    });
}
```

[Proof](https://github.com/parhelium/laboratory/tree/master/meteor/pretty-logs)

### Update

In comments author of question asked why `chalk.enabled` is necessary to make it working with meteor.

The reason is that `chalk.supportsColor` returns `false`, which stops `chalk` from creating colorful texts.

When you use `chalk.enabled = true` then you force `chalk` to always format text.

Comment: Tha worked, thanks! do you lnow why in meteor I have to call `chalk.enabled = true` but it isn't necessary on a standalone nodejs script?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, although I still don't understand why `chalk.supportsColor` would return `false` on a Meteor app but return `true` on a plain nodejs script.

Answer (score 1):

I got chalk NPM package working on in Meteor Server with 256 colors:

```
import Chalk from 'chalk';
const chalk = new Chalk.constructor({enabled: true, level: 2});
console.log(chalk.red('AHA'));
console.log(`${chalk.orange('AHA')}`);
```

I've not been able to get it working on the Chrome Console yet.

Comment: On the Chrome console, you need to use CSS for color.